# make onhover skip inner divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some svgs in a div. The div's border changes color on hover, but if the mouse is over the inner svgs, the color change does not happen. I am looking for a way to simply "skip" the svgs, so if the mouse is anywhere over the parent div, the border color changes.

heres an example of a div with the inner svgs:

```
<div class="blocks2">
    <Nav.Link style={{transform:'translate(-2px,11px)', color:'rgba(0, 101, 252,.44)'}}href="/BeatFrame">
     LinLog
    <div class="babyarcade" style {{top:'-2px', height:'144px', borderWidth: '4px',opacity:'100%'}} >
      <div style={{transform:'translate(9px,32px)'}}>
        <img src={Datalens2} class='PaintFrame'></img>
        <img src={Datavec} class='datavec'></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Nav.Link>
 </div>
```

and here is the css for the parent div *babyarcade*.

```
.babyarcade{
  left:-12px;
  top:27px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 136px;
  width:144px;
  border-width: 4px;
  border: solid;
  opacity: 19%;
  border-radius: 19px;
  border-color:rgba(145, 255, 0,0.005);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 9px 9px rgba(216, 231, 255, 0.06),
  inset 0 0 0px rgba(143,144, 145, .06), 01px 0px 9px
  rgba(239, 234, 219,0.6), -9px -7px 9px rgba(244,248,253,.06),
  inset 0px 4px 2px rgba(239, 234, 219, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 190ms ease-in;
}

.babyarcade:hover {
  animation: babyarcadehover;
  animation-duration: .09s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

as always, thanks for your help friends.

Comment: Could you include an [mcve]? If not, at least your CSS/SCSS would be helpful; there's no apparent `hover` in the JSX you've provided...

Comment: I added the css; if its much more helpful i can produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: minimal reproducible example will be nice :)